# Searching for a string in a XML file and printing the location in the menu tree - Python

Tags: python

I have a xml file that contains the menu structure. I want to search for a menu name or application name and if it matches, I want to print the complete path in the tree.

Here is a part of the xml file:

```
  <menu name="main_menu" display="Main Menu">
    <menu name="A" display="A" 
      <menu name="X" display="X" >
        <application name="M" display="M"/>
        <application name="N" display="N"/>
      </menu>
    <menu name="B" display="B" 
      <menu name="Y" display="Y" >
        <application name="O" display="O"/>
        <application name="P" display="P"/>
      </menu>
```

I am trying to search by the name that matches in XML file and print the location. For example:

If I search for `"P"`, it will print `"B", "Y", "P"`.

Or If I search for `"Y"`, it will print `"B", "Y"`.

I have tried this so far:

```
def findLocation(name):
    xmlLocation = "menu.xml"

    tree = ET.parse(xmlLocation)
    root = tree.getroot()
    parent_map = {c:p for p in tree.iter() for c in p} 
    for item in tree.iterfind('.//menu/..'):
        if item.find('menu').text.encode('utf-8') == name:
            print parent_map[item].find('name').text

findLocation("Y")
```

But it doesn't print anything. Can you suggest me how I should proceed with this?

Comment: `item.find('menu').text.encode('utf-8') == name` - why the `.encode('utf-8')`? This should be completely unnecessary. Also, none of your XML elements even has any `text`.

Comment: Also, please clarify if you are using the `lxml` package or the built-in `xml` package.

Comment: @tomalak, this is a modified/simplified version of the actual xml I have. The encode is necessary to show some of the texts properly. I thought if I want to get the value of `menu name`, I need to call it by `parent_map[item].find('name').text`?

Comment: @Tomalak, I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some function like this (recursive but for xml's with restricted depth it's OK):

```
def find_location(tree, target):
    stack = []
    root = tree.getroot()

    def helper(child):  # recursive part
        name = dict(child.items())['name']
        if name == 'target':
            return [name]
        children = child.getchildren()
        for c in children:
            ret = helper(c)
            if ret and ret[-1] == target:
                return [name] + ret
        return [name]
    # you can cahnge it if you need it, for instance, if only "Main Menu" parsing required
    for child in root:
        result = helper(child)
        if result and result[-1] == target:
            return result
    return []
```

Usage:

```
tree = ET.parse("menu.xml")
location = find_location(tree, 'M')
print(location)
Out:
['main_menu', 'A', 'X', 'M']

location = find_location(tree, 'N')
print(location)
Out:
['main_menu', 'A', 'X', 'N']

location = find_location(tree, 'Y')
print(location)
Out:
['main_menu', 'B', 'Y']

location = find_location(tree, 'P')
print(location)
Out:
['main_menu', 'B', 'Y', 'P']

location = find_location(tree, 'Z')  # no such name in XML
print(location)
Out:
[]
```

NB: if there's more than one element with target name, this code will return first occurence.

You can easily adopt this or just crop first element from lists and the print an ouptut:

```
for node in location[1:]:
    print(node)

Out:
'B'
'Y' 
'P'
```

I've used such xml (slighly modified because this one from post broken or so):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <menu name="main_menu" display="Main Menu">
    <menu name="A" display="A" >
      <menu name="X" display="X" >
        <application name="M" display="M"/>
        <application name="N" display="N"/>
      </menu>
    </menu>
    <menu name="B" display="B" >
      <menu name="Y" display="Y" >
        <application name="O" display="O"/>
        <application name="P" display="P"/>
      </menu>
    </menu>
    </menu>
</data>
```

Comment: This is working properly but I was wondering if it's possible to search by the`name` and print the respective `display`? For example, I want to search by `main_menu` but print `Main Menu`?

Comment: @Russo probably yes if you'l get item by key "display" or another key in `dict(child.items())[key]`. But that case you shold return list of tuples lile [(<display>, <name>)] or so.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was able to do it by returning `[display, name]` and then by printing `[y for x,y in enumerate(location[2:]) if x%2 == 0]`. I used `location[2:]`, because I didn't want to print `Main Menu`. Thanks again :)